# Illegal Array Initialisation? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class My {
    float[] arr=new float[]{0.1f,0.2f};

    arr[0]=0.2f;

    public static void main(String []args) {
        My my= new My();
        System.out.println(my.arr[0]);
    }
}
```

I got errors:

```
My.java: 4 : error: ']' expected

arr[0]=0.2f;

^
My.java: 4 : error: ';' expected

arr[0]=0.2f;

^

My.java: 4 : error: illegal start of type

arr[0]=0.2f;

^
My.java: 4 : error: <identifier> expected

arr[0]=0.2f;

^
```

Is there any way to use `arr[0]=somevalue;` ? Like they do in C?

Comment: They even don't do that in C outside of functions.

Comment: Then how should I change the first element in arr?

Comment: By doing that in a method. Or in a constructor (not sure if they count as methods).

Answer (score 4):

You can either fix the initializer of `arr` to hold the right value from the start

```
float[] arr=new float[]{0.2f,0.2f};
```

or you can change your class to change the value inside the constructor:

```
public class My {
    float[] arr=new float[]{0.1f,0.2f};

    public My() {
        arr[0]=0.2f;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare array inside a `block or function`, without using `Array as field`

```
public class My{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float[] arr = new float[] { 0.1f, 0.2f };
        arr[0] = 0.2f;
        //My my = new My();
        System.out.println(arr[0]);
    }
}
```

Array as a field using constructor

```
public class My{

    private float[] arr = null;

    private My() {
        arr = new float[] { 0.1f, 0.2f };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        My my = new My();
        System.out.println(my.arr[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If he needs that as a field of the class, this is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the initializer of arr value and declare array inside a class.

```
public class My
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        My my = new My();
        System.out.println( my.arr[0] );
    }
    private float[] arr = new float[]
                        { 0.1f, 0.2f };
}
```